# know the table names plus doing a count

Tags: oracle, sas

I've go the following question:

How would you get the table name and the count of that table with SAS?

If I was using Oracle SQL, I would generate a metaquery and spool it , with a query like below :

```
spool test.sql
SELECT 'select '||''''||table_name||''''||',count(*) from '||table_name FROM all_tables;
spool off
```

Once spool , I would run the whole query, which would give me queries like below

```
SELECT 'table_called_toto',COUNT(*) FROM table_called_toto;
```

Once ran, I would have results like that one:

```
table_called_toto,20
```

Does something similar exist in SAS? And if yes, how should I do it?

Comment: I tried googling - 'list of table names in sas', and 2 of the top 5 results answered this question. =/

Comment: Hi Robert, list of tables names and the counts.`how to have the table names plus the count in sas`. We are between people who knows the tacit rules and I think , the trust has not been breach.

Comment: @AndyK What Rob's correctly pointing out is that this question is easily answered on your own.  You didn't need to ask it here.

Comment: Hi Joe, fair enough. I would do better due diligence next time.

Comment: @joe good point. http://tinypic.com/r/2ibdg04/8

Comment: Fair enough, I got your point -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for macro programming.  But you can also query sashelp.vtable which contains metadata about SAS tables. If you had a list of tables I would do something like the following:

```
proc sql;
select libname, memname, nobs
from sashelp.vtable 
where upcase(libname)='WORK' and upcase(memname) in (Select upcase(table_name) from all_tables);
quit;
```

Note that the comparisons are case sensitive.